# Jekyll photo gallery without plugins

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, gallery

Is there a way to generate a Jekyll photo gallery which does not use plugins? I tried some, but it wasn't GitHub Pages friendly.

Now I'm using markdown, where I specify which pictures should be displayed, but I want to find some generic way to do this.

Comment: You can use Javascript libraries like [Fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this in your yml (in your .md file):

```
images:
  - image: /uploads/image5.jpg
  - image: /uploads/image6.jpg
  - image: /uploads/image7.jpg
```

And this in your layout file:

```
{% for item in page.images %}
<div class="lightbox" id="lightbox{{ forloop.index }}">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <img class="close" src="/img/close.svg" />
      <img class="next" src="/img/next.svg" />
      <img class="prev" src="/img/prev.svg" />
      <div class="item" style="background: url('{{ item.image }}') center center no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Together with some CSS and jQuery this can be your own custom lightbox. The jQuery should toggle the (next) lightbox. Something like this:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.lightbox').hide().next().show();
});
```

**UPDATE: I have created a [simple lightbox for Jekyll](http://jekyllcodex.org/without-plugin/lightbox/) that anyone can use without understanding javascript, HTML or CSS (or even Jekyll).**

Comment: This is awesome. Example looks really great. Shame there is no Readme how to use it, but I can follow through the code and try to implement similar functions. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I would advice you to use a premade javascript solution like Fancybox 3 (as Karthikeyan adviced) if you do not fully understand CSS and jQuery.

Comment: Very nice. JoostS, the example website source is no longer existing or public. Does it, in fact, now use the lightbox from jekyll codex?

Comment: Thank you. I removed the broken link. Please use the Jekyll Codex lightbox.